# Use versioned lambda for s3 event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working with s3 events and I'd like to use a versioned lambda. Here's my input:

```
{
  "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
    {
      "Id": "ImageProcessing",
      "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:*************:function:OnUpload:1",
      "Events": [
        "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
        "s3:ObjectCreated:Post"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, my lambda is named OnUpload, version 1, but I keep getting a:

```
An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Unable to validate the following destination configuration
```

However, it works when I omit the version:

```
{
  "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
    {
      "Id": "Processing",
      "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:*************:function:OnUpload",
      "Events": [
        "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
        "s3:ObjectCreated:Post"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It works.

Is there a way to use a versioned lambda for my s3 bucket event?

EDIT:

I'm using the AWS CLI, and here's the command I'm running:
`aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --bucket ... --notification-configuration file://...`

EDIT 2:
The first code snippet (the one with the version) works when I use the Amazon Console, but not when I use the CLI.

Comment: I checked using the arn with version, and had no issues. Can you double check your setup? Also are you using CLI to set it up?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I'm using the CLI for this, I've updated my post to the exact command I'm using